# retrieve variables in a txt of multiple values in php

Tags: php, text, text-files

content in txt file:

```
<test@test.com>: connect to test.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out
recipient=test@test.com
offset=00000
status=0.0.0
action=delayed
reason=connect to test.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out


<test234@test234.com>: connect to e-mail.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out
recipient=test234@test234.com
offset=00000
status=0.0.0
action=delayed
reason=connect to test234.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out
```

I need to get in variables in the txt file:
for example:

```
$email =    test234@test234.com
$content = : connect to e-mail.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out
             recipient=test234@test234.com
             offset=00000
             status=0.0.0
             action=delayed
             reason=connect to test234.com[00.00.00.0]:0: Connection timed out
```

I try but not working

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$connect)
{
  die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('test',$connect);


// txt file

$file = fopen("email_errors.txt", "r") or exit ("Unable to open file");

while ( ($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {

   // get the email <email@email.com>
   preg_match_all('/\<(.+)\>/', $line, $coincidencias);

foreach ($coincidencias[1] AS $email) 
{
   // create a query and insert into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO errormailer(id_error, email, description, fecha)    VALUES(NULL,'".$email."',' $description (the description)',now());";

    echo '<pre>'.$sql. '</pre>';
    mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```

I can not find the right way how to do it
I need to get them in variables for storage in databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$connect)
{
  die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('test',$connect);


// txt file

$file = fopen("email_errors.txt", "r") or exit ("Unable to open file");

$i = 0;

while ( ($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {

   // get the email <email@email.com>
   if (preg_match('/\<(.+)\>/', $line, $email)) {
     $coincidencias[] = $email[1];  
   }
   if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0) {
        $still_empty = false;
        $content[$i] .= preg_replace('/\<.+\>: /', '', $line);
   } else {
       if (!$still_empty) {
            $i++;   
       }
       $still_empty = true; 
   }
}

$i = 0;
foreach ($coincidencias as $email) 
{
    // create a query and insert into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO errormailer(id_error, email, description, fecha) VALUES(NULL,'".$email."','".$content[$i]."',now());";
    echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre>';
    $i++;
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and do not know what to do. php display notice,Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in upload.php on line 29.         I'm checking

Comment: @Eduardo What do you mean by _do not know what to do_? What kind of help do you need?